# How to debug unmanaged Delphi codes from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, delphi, visual-studio-2012, hydra

I have the Delphi project calling C# dll now the problem is dll assembly types that are called from HydraModuleController assembly.GetType() statement which is returning null values for one or more types. I tried to debug Delphi codes from Visual Studio by the following steps. 
    Debug -> Attach to process...
    Select the running process.
    Click the "Select..." button to the right of "Attach to".
    Select "Debug these code types"
    Check Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) for .NET 3.5 or less, or Managed (v4.0) for .NET 4.0 or   later. 
    Click OK, click Attach.

but when still can't debug from VS. How should I do? 
This is Delphi code that call the AssemblyResolver from C# dll.

```
try
 fAssembly.CreateInstance_2('WPFProj.AssemblyResolver', true);
   except
```

Here is Delphi code called dll assembly types.

```
procedure THYManagedModuleController.CreateManagedControllerInstance;
var
  lTypes:PSafeArray;
  lType:_Type;
  lStart,lEnd,i:integer;
  lVariant: OleVariant;
begin
  lTypes := fAssembly.GetTypes();
  SafeArrayLock(lTypes);
......
end
```

Here is the AssemblyResolver.cs in WPF project.

```
 public class AssemblyResolver
{
    static AssemblyResolver()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

    }

    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        Stream stream =
    asm.GetManifestResourceStream(String.Format("WPFProj.Includes.{0}.dll",
    an.Name));
        if (stream == null)
            return null;
        byte[] block = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
        Assembly resolved = Assembly.Load(block);
        return resolved;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you even debug delphi from VS? Is it ppssible? How does the delphi application is loading and using the c#? Dll?

Comment: I am not sure. I googled and found some thing saying unmanaged codes can be debug in VS. That's why I'm trying. Do you have any idea to debug unmanaged code inside delphi?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot debug Delphi code from Visual Studio. Visual Studio debugging relies on debug info using Microsoft's proprietary PDB format. The Delphi compiler produces debug info in its own proprietary DCU format.

To debug Delphi code you need the Delphi IDE, RAD Studio. To debug your C# code you need the Microsoft IDE, Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Now I could solve that problem. Actually, as we are using .net dll in Delphi exe, we can catch the exceptions from Visual Studio for unmanaged codes inside Hydra for delphi. I did some changes inside Visual Studio. Go to project -> projectproperties -> Choose Debug mode -> Choose Start External Program -> Browse the Delphi exe file path. Then go to Debug -> Exceptions -> Check Common Language Runtime Exception.
That's all. 
Then when you run your .net project it also run Delphi project and catch the exceptions of unmanaged codes inside Delphi.

Comment: This appears to be the answer to a different question. You asked how to debug delphi code from VS.